# How to validate that certain tab in browser is active using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I' just starting learning about selenium web driver using eclipse, I need to validate that certain tab in web page is active , 
when I inspect element of it I found that it`s class name containing the word active " li class="first tab active "" and this inside ul class , my question is how to get current tab li class name to check then if it contains active word ??

Thanks A lot for any helping answer.

Comment: notice that the name of each tab is exist inside the tab li between <span>, I think this may help.

Comment: Try an XPath expression, like `By.XPath("//ul/li[@class='first tab active']/h1")` or such to get the active tab's title and compare it to what you expect.

Comment: I tried to use Assert.assertTrue if body contains first-tab active but it didn`t work !

Comment: using webelement.getpagesource(); then check in it for first tab active works fine

Comment: But still can't get title of active tab using xpath !